# Maximum slope of a sine wave

Tags: differential

For a signal with amplitude,

$$V = A\sin (\omega t)$$

any idea at what point the maximum slope (gradient, dv/dt)  is? I have gone through the method of differentiating which yields

$$A\omega \cos(\omega t) \tag{i}$$

and then doing a second differential, which yields

$$-A \omega^2 \sin (\omega t) \tag{ii}$$

Equating (i) to 0 and then substituting back into (ii) to find which point is where I got stuck. I can do this with a normal equation but trigonometry sometimes confuses me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to set the second derivative to zero, in order to find the extrema of the first derivative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The maximum slope for a sine wave that has no offset and an ampliutde \$A_0\$ occurs exactly during the zero crossings. Its value is simply \$A_0 \omega\$

The derivation is 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} A_0 \sin (\omega t) = A_0 \omega \cos(\omega t)
$$
which gives the slope of the sine wave.

The maximum of the cosine is 1. Therefore the maximum is \$A_0 \omega\$.
$$
\max \left\{ A_0 \omega \cos(\omega t) \right\}= A_0 \omega 
$$
The results makes sense, since intuitively the slope has to increase with the amplitude as well as the frequency.

Comment: I always remember that the maximum slew rate is Pi/2 times that of a sawtooth of the same p-p amplitufe. (i.e. ~1.57* the sawtooth slew rate)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I could not understood well, but I think you done a mistake (or two).

The maximum of the *slope* is where *its* (of the slope) derivative is 0, then you should take the slope (the first derivative), derive it  and put this second derivative equal to zero.

P.S. You also differentiating wrong:

\$\frac{d}{dx} sin(x) = cos(x) \$

and

\$\frac{d}{dx} cos(x) = -sin(x) \$

Then, ...look at the intersection with x axis... ;-)

Comment: He is not asking for the maximum of the sine wave, he is asking at what point you can find the *maximum derivative*.

Comment: @DerStrom8, I can't understand your comment and the downvote; I answered exactly how to find the maximum slope, i.e  the **second derivative**, that is the maximum of the prime derivative, and I suggested also how to look for the maximum slope

"*Then, ...look at the intersection with x axis... ;-)*"

Comment: Just to be clear I didn't downvote you, that must have been someone else. Anyway, I missed the last comment in your answer, but the first part of your answer is a bit confusing. The maximum *slope* is **not** where the *first* derivative is 0. I think you need to specify "The maximum of the *slope* is where the **second derivative** is zero, not where the **first derivative** is zero

Comment: @DerStrom8, no problem for the downvote but thanks for the precisation. :-) Regarding to my answer, I edited for say it better, but I never said that the first derivative of the signal is the maximum slope.  
I said that **a maximum is where the derivative is zero**, therefore, I specified immediately after, to find the **maximum slope** we need to get the derivative, **derive it one more time**, and put the result equal to zero. It isn't?

Comment: I think we might be hitting a bit of a language barrier? This quote: "**The maximum of the slope is where its (of the slope) derivative is 0**" suggests that you are saying the maximum value of the slope (that is, the highest slope) is where the derivative is zero, which is not the case. I think this is what threw me off, I misread what you were trying to say.

Comment: @DerStrom8, probably my electronics are not as good as that of other frequenters (I am here, above all, to learn) but my English is obviously much worse. :-) Feel free to correct my english.

Comment: Hmm, something still seems fishy with your answer but I can't put my finger on it. I tried making an edit but my correction didn't make much sense either so I rolled it back. Maybe someone else can edit it and make more sense